# Make new Buffer using portion of other Buffer in Node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, amazon-web-services, buffer

I am currently making an AWS call in Node.js.  That call returns a buffer.

```
  var aws = new AWS.S3(); 
   var params = {
       Bucket: s3config.bucket, 
       Key: s3config.tile_directory + filepath //, 
//     Range: 'bytes=0-' + (this.HEADER_SIZE - 1)
   };

   var ts = this; 
   aws.getObject(params, function(err, data){
       var buff = data.Body; 
   }
```

I would like to create a new Buffer that would be the equivalent of if I used the `range:` param that is commented out. So I would like bits 0 - `ts.HEADER_SIZE` of the buffer so that I do not later have to make three different AWS calls with different ranges.

I tried:

```
var newBuff = new Buffer(data.Body, 0, ts.HEADER_SIZE - 1);
```

But it seems to just give me back the same Buffer I started with.  Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The first thing you need to do is create a new Buffer of the size `ts.HEADER_SIZE`.

```
var newBuff = new Buffer(ts.HEADER_SIZE)
```

Then you can copy the portion of the larger Buffer into this new Buffer.

```
data.Body.copy(newBuff, 0, 0, ts.HEADER_SIZE - 1);
```

The value of `newBuff` will now be the subset that you want.